# Why cant i run this init container as root

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to chown a mounted volume using a init container, because the volume is owned by root. But the init container is unable to become root. This is what i gave in the init container:

```
 init_container {
   name    = "init-eclipse"
   image   = "busybox:latest"      
   command = [ "chown","-R","1000:1000","/data"]

      security_context {
    run_as_user = "0"
    privileged = "true"
    allow_privilege_escalation = "true"
    read_only_root_filesystem = "false"
    run_as_non_root = "false"
    capabilities {
      add = ["CAP_SYS_ADMIN","CHOWN",
             "FOWNER",
              "DAC_OVERRIDE"]
 
    drop = [
  "ALL"]
    }
  }
   volume_mount {
     mount_path = "/data"
     name       = "home-coder-vol-${data.coder_workspace.me.owner}-${lower(data.coder_workspace.me.name)}"
   } 

}
```

I get error like chown /data/.snapshot not permitted.
This is inside OKE Cluster on OCI cloud if that matters.

I tried adding some stuff given on IBM Cloud for a similar thing:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cam/3.2.1.0?topic=ts-troubleshooting-issues-in-installation-cloud-automation-manager-cloud-private-openshift-cloud

I see a lot of people doing same thing with init container to chown mounted folders, but I cant do it. Why is this happening? Do we need to have any special provision in k8s for this to work?

**EDIT**
So i changed the command to print whoami to a file which i read from the container. It said root. So the INIT container IS running as root, but it cannot chown.

Comment: Have you checked the image you are using for the existence of the root user?

Comment: Kubernetes can [do this on its own](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods) if the Pod spec includes `fsGroup`; would that be an easier approach?

Comment: @MarkoE - Yes it has root

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not clear on fsgroup. What fsGroup should i give. Is that the GID on the NFS folder? I dont have access to the linux properties of the NFS folder. I believe it is owned by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init container is not being given the necessary privileges to chown the mounted volume. In order for the init container to have the necessary permissions, you will need to set the securityContext of the initContainer to `runAsUser: 0` and set the `allowPrivilegeEscalation to true`. Additionally, you will need to add the CHOWN, FOWNER, and DAC_OVERRIDE capabilities to the `capabilities.add list` and the ALL capability to the `capabilities.drop list`. Doing this should give the init container the necessary privileges to chown the volume.

Refer to this [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), [blog from kubernetes community forum](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/write-permissions-on-volume-mount-with-security-context-fsgroup-option/16524).

Comment: I added all that, still no go. Edited code above to reflect new code

Comment: can i know the error you are observing?

Comment: I am getting error like chown /data/.snapshot not permitted.

Comment: Seems to be you have  given an extra space at Open braces and can you Correct it like this `command = ["chown","-R","1000:1000","/data"]` and have a try and refer to this [Operations not permitted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54525/chown-changing-ownership-of-operation-not-permitted) link

Answer (score 0):

If using NFS, make sure that `no_root_squash` is set on the NFS server /etc/exports for the directory where the file is present.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).